# Create a 3x3x3 array. Fill it with random values from 0 to 9. Output the array. Find output the 3 smallest and the 3 largest values

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Create a 3x3x3 array. Fill it with random values from 0 to 9. Output the array. Find output the 3 smallest and the 3 largest values. I continue to get erros from the compiler along with it stating issues with my initialization. I do not know why.

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void initialize(int x[3][3][3]) int column; int row; int layer; int large1;
void find(int x[3][3][3]);              //to find number to fill


int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int x[3][3][3];
    int large1, large2, large3, small1, small2, small3, row, column, layer;

    initialize(x[3][3][3]);
    int x = RAND() % 0 + 10;
}

void initialize(int x[3][3][3]){
    int large1, large2, large3, small1, small2, small3;

    large1 = large2 = large3 = INT_LARGE;

    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
            for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++){
                if (x[r][c][l]>large1){
                    large3 = large2;
                    large2 = large1;
                    large1 = x[r][c][l];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << large1 << large2 << large3 << endl;
    system("pause");
}

`
```

Comment: Don't make us guess. Include the error message(s). I suspect there's at least one on the `int x = RAND...` line as you already have an `x` defined.

Comment: Error 2 error C2660: 'initialize' : function does not take 1 arguments 
Error 3 error C2040: 'x' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int [3][3][3]' 
Error 4 error C3861: 'RAND': identifier not found 
Error 5 error C2065: 'large1' : undeclared identifier 
Error 6 error C2065: 'large1' : undeclared identifier 
Error 7 error C2065: 'row' : undeclared identifier 
Error 8 error C2065: 'column' : undeclared identifier 
Error 9 error C2065: 'layer' : undeclared identifier

Comment: 10 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "initialize" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (int) 
 13 IntelliSense: identifier "row" is undefined 
 14 IntelliSense: identifier "column" is undefined 
 15 IntelliSense: identifier "layer" is undefined 
 11 IntelliSense: identifier "RAND" is undefined 
 12 IntelliSense: identifier "large1" is undefined

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using this

Comment: This seems very much like homework, please make sure you ask questions so you learn from it. Read up on variables and Java syntax.

Comment: The error message in comment is hard to read. Plase edit the question and include them in the question, with 4 spaces of indent (have the system treat it as code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- remove junk ` at the beginning and the end of the code
- add a semicolon between `void initialize(int x[3][3][3])` and `int column; int row; int layer; int large1;`
- `initialize(x[3][3][3]);` is bad because it access out of range. use `initialize(x);`
- in `int x = RAND() % 0 + 10;` there are three errors:

  - `x` conflicts with `int x[3][3][3];` Please change its name.
  - `RAND()` is not in the standard. Did you mean `rand()`?
  - Do not devide an integer by 0.
- `INT_LARGE` is not defined. Please define it somewhere before using.

Answer (score 0):

without an error message it's hard to guess at what's going wrong.

That said, `int x = RAND() % 0 + 10;` stood out like a beacon, so I'm guessing that's your problem.  You can't use modulus (or divide) with 0, and modulus goes before addition.  You can fix this with parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that your declaration of `initialize` doesn't end with a semicolon but is followed by `... ]) int column; int row; int layer; int large1;`. That doesn't parse.

The second problem is that the `int x = RAND` line is entirely pointless. It redefines `x` and would happen after `initialize`. Which is a bad name, because it doesn't initialize anything but instead sorts the elements.

At this point, you really should go back to your books, and then back to the high-level task. Make sure that `initialize` actually initializes `x`, and then put the actual sorting logic in `find`. It looks like you were asked to complete a program, and you entirely forgot about `find`.